# PM2 keeps re-starting on Google app engine

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, pm2

When I run my app locally with PM2 v 3.5.0 all works fine, however when I deploy it on Google GCP app engine Flex environment, PM2 keeps restarting the app.

here are my PM2 config file

```
{
  "apps": [{
    "name"        : "prod_client",
    "script"      : "./bin/www",
    "exec_mode": "cluster_mode",
    "instances": 1,
    "watch"       : false,
    "env": {
      "NODE_ENV": "production"
    }
    },{
    "name"       : "prod_api",
    "script"     : "./src/server/apiServer.js",
    "exec_mode": "cluster_mode",
    "instances": 1,
    "watch"       : false,
    "env": {
      "NODE_ENV": "production"
    }
  }]
}
```

interestingly I do not get any proper useful logs. Note here that, everything works fine in local machine, PM2 doesn't complain.

Comment: PM2 has a default Load Balancer and a default Auto Restart option. I think this is interfering on the Flex environment. Have you tried to disable both of this features and allow the instance to crash so you could see the Logs in Stackdriver Login?

Comment: @NahuelVarela haven't tried that. I will check , but now some how it worked with different code base (which I had it for staging environment deployment). Its strange it worked and there is absolutely no difference in code except some configurations like DB config etc

Comment: Nice to see it's working now. Could you post the steps that led to resolution? So it will help others in the same situation.

Comment: @NahuelVarela I already mentioned in my previous comment, it worked with different code base ( two code base one for staging, one for production, two branches, ideally only envs and constants will change) so in this case staging code with production env and constants worked fine with no change in code, thats why I am saying its strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had this same issue. It was due to PM2 trying to write files to storage, which Google AppEngine (GAE) does not generally support (more to follow on this). Also, we have not got it fully working because, sadly, there's a problem with the memory check `pidusage` command on GAE that has not yet been resolved [[1]](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/4360).

So, to address the issue initially, we used the configuration to redirect logging and pidfile paths to `/dev/stdout` and `/dev/null` respectively. This got PM2 working, but it still was not working quite right. It was struggling to read the pidfile, for example.

However, GAE does allow for tmp files (we were using Standard, but I imagine Flex has similar support)[[2]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-temp-files). So, we removed the pidfile configuration and instead, changed the `start` script to set `PM2_HOME=/tmp/.pm2`. This got us as close to working as we could, given the `pidusage` issue mentioned earlier.

```sh
PM2_HOME=/tmp/.pm2 pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production --no-daemon --mini-list
```

The `ecosystem.config.js` configuration was something like:

```js
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: "service",
            script: "main.js",
            kill_timeout: 15000,
            max_memory_restart: "400M",
            exec_mode: "cluster",
            instances: 1,
            out_file: "/dev/stdout",
            error_file: "/dev/stderr",
            env: {
                NODE_ENV: "development",
                BLAH: "1",
            },
            env_production: {
                NODE_ENV: "production",
                BLAH: "0",
            },
        },
    ],
};
```